# iPhone Accurate Reverse Geolocation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-location, iphone-sdk-3.1

I want to get the most accurate location possible in my app. I have tried in the past (about 2 months ago) and I used to get some quite odd results. Like one time it would get a location pretty accurate (down to a few doors down), then I would try again 5 minutes later in the same spot and I would get somewhere a few kms away.

So what I really want to do, is have Core Location searching for 5-10 seconds (on a timer) and have it pull out the street and suburb, but if the street is not quite accurate, then just take the suburb.

Using the Maps app, when it gets down to the blue dot, I know its really accurate and has my location within 20 meters - in this case I would like to output the street and suburb, but when it has a larger radius I know its not as accurate - in this case I just want the suburb.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the horizontalAccuracy property of the CLLocation object and depending on that value output either street, subburb or even just city.